# [React-Native]Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision

Tags: ios, react-native

> Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision:

[image: Failed to build DependencyGraph: @providesModule naming collision]

Does anyone know how can I fix this react-native problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this with version 3.38.1 of react-native-router-flux. Downgrading to 3.38.0 resolved the errors.

EDIT: Adding GitHub issue
There looks to be an issue already for this - https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/1809